# font-awesome.min.css failed to load

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am getting this error when I access my html files offline:

> GET
>   http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
>   net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED

Since this file doesn't get loaded the page takes longer to load.
The error points at the line where jQuery link is added.

```
<script src="/MyApp/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To oversome,I have downloaded the font-awesome.min.css and added reference in the html file as `<link type="text/css" href="/MyApp/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` But this doesn't seem to work.
Can anyone tell me how to overcome this error?

Comment: Not following you re "error points at the line where jQuery link is added"

Comment: That's basically path problem.try to provide full url there or do like this:-   `<link type="text/css" href="../MyApp/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` and `<script src="../MyApp/js/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: can u verify if the font awesome file you referenced is actually being loaded?